# AVCaptureOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection never completes on iPhone5

Tags: ios

In my application I am displaying a **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** and then capturing a still image when the user clicks a button using the **captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection** function in **AVCaptureOutput**.  This has worked well for me up until the iPhone 5, on which it never completes.

My setup code is:

```
...
self.imageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[self.imageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

self.captureSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.captureSession addInput:self.rearFacingDeviceInput];
[self.captureSession addOutput:self.imageOutput];
[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
self.previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 427);
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;

[self.captureSession startRunning];
[outputSettings release];
```

My capture method is:

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.imageOutput.connections){
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]){
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ){
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}

//code to abort if not return 'soon'
...

[self.imageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error){

    //use image here

}];
```

captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection never completes for me using an iPhone5

I have tested:

- It isn't OS 6 as this code works on both an iPhone 4s and an iPod (iPod touch (4th generation) that have been updated
- The captureSession is running
- videoConnection is not nil
- imageOutput is not nil

Also:

- I'm using this method and not UIImagePickerController because I need to put the preview as a subview.
- calling **stopRunning** on the capture Session takes several seconds on the iPhone 5 as well

Comment: I think there are two reasons that cause this problem. 1) You are in a special thread. 2) This device does not support the camera parameters you set. The description of this method says: A block that will be called when the still image capture is complete.The block will be passed a CMSampleBuffer object containing the image data or an NSError object if an image could not be captured.

So, have you ever tried to print the reason of NSError?

Comment: is imageSampleBuffer empty?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code works fine. Tested for both iPhone 4 and 5, (baseSDK 7.1, under ARC).

Few things you have to consider.

1) be sure you set rearFacingDeviceInput properly,

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[self setRearFacingDeviceInput:[AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil]];
```

2) as [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644934/vincent) mentioned, there will be an error, try to log both an error and imageSampleBuffer

3) session's -startRunning and -stopRunning operations takes long time to complete (seconds, even 5-6s), those methods doesn't return until they are done all the work, to avoid blocked UI you shouldn't call these methods on main thread, one way is using GCD

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
});
```

If still captureStillImageAsynchronously doesn't complete (to ensure that, add breakpoint in block, and log everything) you should check your device's camera. I believe your code works on all iPhone 5 devices. Hope this helps, good luck.